# CI/CD for Multi-Container laravel + Nginx Application on ESC fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-pipeline

I want to deploy a laravel + nginx application on aws ecs fargate. i just want to discuss the best possible practice for this from infrastructure point of view. currently i am thinking of creating 2 docker images for larave and nginx separately and start 2 containers inside ecs task. but then there is this weird setup in codebuild, for example i have to setup either 2 codebuild projects for laravel and nginx respectively or a single one with single buildspec file. but then i am having trouble with build Artifacts from this setup (single buildspec for laravel and nginx). means how to copy both images to one artifact so that deploy stage can deploy these images to respective containers.
i want to decouple the webserver (nginx) from main application, hence idea of separating the containers. that way it would be easy to just update or change the nginx configs, if needed, and deploy them.
can you guys share your thoughts if this is the right way or are there any other possible best practices for such a pipeline. open to all suggestions
thank you.